# I want to get the omnikey readear running status

Tags: hid, omnikey

I have a hid omnikey 3121 reader. I want to check what's the status of that reader if it's running or idle.

Suppose if I run my program it should tell what the reader is doing. For example

Reader1 - Currently running
Reader2 - Idle
Reader3 - Running
Reader4 - Idle
.
.
.
ReaderN - Idle

Comment: Hi there, did you at least try something or just asking solution for some kind of task?